# How to make it in Pascal triangle shape. Meaning 1 in first row, and then 1,1 in second row, 1,2,1 in third

Tags: python

I finished the code and it worked with the value that i put in. but i just dont know how to make it return in a form like pascal triangle.

```
import math

n=int(input("choose your whole number"))

def J(n,r):
    return math.factorial (n)//(math.factorial (n-r)*math.factorial (r))

def G(z):
     for n in range (z+1):
         for r in range (n+1):
               print (J(n,r), end=" ")

G(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a newline after printing each new row. If you want to pad the top of the pyramide (so it looks like a balanced pyramide) you need to print an offset as well:

```
def G(z):
    for n in range (z+1):
        # Pad the numbers so they appear in a pyramide
        print('  ' * (z-n), end="")
        for r in range (n+1):
            # Add the ljust-bit to make sure the numbers 
            # gets an even spacing
            print (str(J(n,r)).ljust(4), end="")
        # New line after each row
        print()
```

Example:

> choose your whole number **5**

Output:

```
          1   
        1   1   
      1   2   1   
    1   3   3   1   
  1   4   6   4   1   
1   5   10  10  5   1
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple: you need a newline after you finish printing the numbers on a line. Just add an empty print statement (careful with the indentation):

```
def G(z):
     for n in range (z+1):
         for r in range (n+1):
               print (J(n,r), end=" ")
         print()
```